# Cómo comparar el contenido de dos DataTable y capturar el resultado en una tercera DataTable?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, poo, datatable

Me explico, tengo dos DataTable con el mismo esquema, la diferencia es que en una tabla tengo más rows que en otra.

Lo que quiero es que las filas de la tabla1 que no están en la tabla2 se almacenen en una tabla3.

Soy nuevo en c# y lo más cerca del resultado esperado es el siguiente ejemplo:

```
// Tabla 1
ComparaVentas c_cabeza100 = new ComparaVentas(xServVentas, usuario, clave);
var dt100 = c_cabeza100.ComparaCabeza(xCodigo, xDia, xMes, xAño);

// Tabla 2
ComparaVentas c_cabeza9 = new ComparaVentas(xServSucursal, usuario, clave);
var dt9 = c_cabeza9.ComparaCabeza(xCodigo, xDia, xMes, xAño);

if (dt100.Rows.Count > dt9.Rows.Count)
{
    IEnumerable<string> numEn100 = dt100.AsEnumerable().Select(row => (string)row["numero"]);
    IEnumerable<string> numEn9 = dt9.AsEnumerable().Select(row => (string)row["numero"]);
    IEnumerable<string> resultado = numEn100.Except(numEn9); // Resultado
    //int filas = resultado.Count();
}
```

El ejemplo de arriba me muestra un array de string pero solo del campo numero. Y lo que quiero lograr es almacenar el resultado en una tercera DataTable con todas las columnas

Comment: Nunca he necesitado hacer esto, lo hago con una vista en la base de datos y sino tienes detrás una BBDD no uses Datatables

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar algo como esto para la intersección

```
var resultado = from t1 in dt100.AsEnumerable()
    join t2 in dt9.AsEnumerable() 
        on !(t1.Field<int>("numero") equals t2.Field<int>("numero"))
    select new { t1, t2 };
```

De esta manera almacenas todas las no existentes en el DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes clonar la tabla y añadir las filas que no están en la otra tabla:

```
 public static DataTable DifTable(DataTable d1, DataTable d2,string ColumnName)
 { 
    DataTable Result;
    Result=d1.Clone();
        IEnumerable<string> IE1 = d1.AsEnumerable().Select(row => (string)row[ColumnName]);
        IEnumerable<string> IE2 = d2.AsEnumerable().Select(row => (string)row[ColumnName]);
        List<string> LDIF = IE1.Except(IE2).ToList();
    LDIF.ForEach(valor=>Result.ImportRow(d1.Select(ColumnName+"='"+valor+"'")[0]));

    return Result;
 }
```

Puedes copiar la tabla y eliminar las filas que están en la otra tabla:

```
  public static DataTable DifTable2(DataTable d1, DataTable d2,string ColumnName)
 { 
    DataTable Result;
    Result=d1.Copy();
          List<string> Ld2 = d2.AsEnumerable().Select(row => (string)row[ColumnName]).ToList();
    Ld2.ForEach(valor=>Result.Rows.Remove(Result.Select(ColumnName+"='"+valor+"'")[0]));

    return Result;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por las respuestas, encontré una pregunta parecida que contenía una respuesta que resolvió mi duda:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713243/compare-two-datatables-and-select-the-rows-that-are-not-present-in-second-table

El código que implementé fue el siguiente:

```
var idsNotIn9 = dt100.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("numero"))
                .Except(dt9.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("numero")));
DataTable dtResultado = (from row in dt100.AsEnumerable()
                         join numero in idsNotIn9
                         on row.Field<string>("numero") equals numero
                         select row).CopyToDataTable();
```